# Tabulator table width is shrinking at first time loading and after drag it is adjusting

Tags: javascript, css, angular, tabulator

[image]
above image show that how tabulator table width is shrinking

but it should show like below image
[image: it should show like this]
here table is shrinking at first time loading like in which is there in first  image and when i drag it is coming but i want it should adjust properly

```js
  this.wormGearTabulatorHeaders = [
            {
                title: "Type", field: "name", headerHozAlign: "left", width: "55%", headerSort: false, hozAlign: "left", editable: false

            },
            {
                title: "Value", headerHozAlign: "center", width: "45%",
                columns: [
                    {
                        title: "Min", field: "minValue",cellEdited: validateWormGear,editable:editCheck, editor: "input", headerSort: false, width: "15%", hozAlign: "right", formatter:
                            decimalFormatter
                        , headerHozAlign: "right"
                        , editorParams: {
                            formatter: decimalFormatter
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Nom", field: "nomValue",cellEdited: validateWormGear, editor: "input", headerSort: false, width: "15%", hozAlign: "right", formatter: decimalFormatter, headerHozAlign: "right"

                        , editorParams: {
                            formatter: decimalFormatter
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Max", field: "maxValue",cellEdited: validateWormGear,editable:editCheck, editor: "input", headerSort: false, width: "15%", hozAlign: "right", formatter: decimalFormatter, headerHozAlign: "right"

                        , editorParams: {
                            formatter: decimalFormatter
                        }
                    },
                ],
            },

        ];
        this.wormGearTabulatorTable = new Tabulator("#wormGearTabulatorTable", {
            maxHeight: "100%",
            maxwidth: "100%",
            data: wormGearTableData,
            layout: "fitDataTable",
            headerSort: false,
            columns: this.wormGearTabulatorHeaders,
        })
```

```html
its html code for same table 
                                        <div id="wormGearTabulatorTable" style="max-height: 100%;max-width: 100%;position: relative;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try setting the default width to `100%` this might solve your issue!

Another thing also can be adjusting it to `100vw` but this depends if the table is shown the entire width of the screen!

```
<div id="wormGearTabulatorTable" style="max-height: 100%;width: 100%;position: relative;"></div>
```